# I can't do selenium java random click

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfynj.png)

I want to do a rondom click with selenium, but I can't. I searched but couldn't find it. I want to choose the sizes in the photo randomly. Because the sizes may be out of stock and my test will fail.

I ask for your support. I tried with list methods and I didn't.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not shared the HTML structure, can't suggest you on the actual code, however see the algorithm below:

**Solution1:** Assuming the dropdown has **select** tag:

1. Get the dropdown values into a Select object, call it **dropdownValues**

   ```
   Select dropdownValues= new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("name of the element")));
   ```
2. Create an instance(object) of Random class and generate a random number in the dropdown index range
3. Select the random index from the dropdownValues

   ```
   dropdownValues.selectByIndex(randomElement);
   ```

**Solution2:** Assuming the dropdown does not have **select** tag:

1. Get the dropdown values into a List, example below

   ```
   List<WebElement> dropdownValues = driver.findElements(By.xpath("enter xpath here"));
   ```
2. Create an instance(object) of Random class like below

   ```
   Random rand = new Random();
   ```
3. Select the random index from the List dropdownValues

   ```
   dropdownValues.get(rand.nextInt(dropdownValues .size()));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

2 approach for this.
1.

```
WebElement InputBox = driver.findElement(by.xpath("xpath of input box"));`
     InputBox.click();
        WebElement DropDownAttribute = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//*[text()='Xs']"));
        DropDownAttribute.click();
```

2.With Loop

```
 List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(by.xapth("Xpath of all the dropdown entity"));
for(WebElement ele:list){
if(ele.getText().equals("Xs")){
ele.click();
}
}
```

Comment: unfortunately these didn't work. I want to click on any size there, not xs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to count the dropdown selections and then generate a random number between 1 and the max number of selections. NOTE: You don't want to include 0 because of the "Size" label inside the dropdown.

```
Random random = new Random();
By selectLocator = By.id("someId"); // the locator for the Size dropdown
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(selectLocator)); // get the Size dropdown element and convert it to a Select element to make it easier to work with
Integer size = dropdown.getOptions().size() + 1; // get the number of OPTIONs and add 1 to avoid selecting the "Size" OPTION
dropdown.selectByIndex(random.nextInt(size)); // select an OPTION based on the generated random number
```

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: What didn't work? Did you receive an error? If so, please post the error here.